# Wakelock and wifilock not working

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wakelock

I have read plenty of tutorial and posts here on SO regarding the use of WakeLock and WifiLock, but still didn't get to a solution of my issue.

I'm writing an app that has, when you start it, the only effect of creating and starting a (foreground) service. This service run two threads that are an UDP broadcast listener (using java.io) and a TCP server (using java.nio). In the onCreate of the service I acquire a wakelock and a wifilock, and I release them in the onDestroy.

Everything works fine as far as the phone is awake, but when the display goes off the UDP broadcast receiver stops receiving broadcast messages, and will not receive any until I switch on again the display. Practically, the locks are not working at all and there is no difference in put them...where am I wrong? I'm sure I'm doing something stupid somewhere, but can't find it by myself.

Here is some code:

This is what Activity does:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onlyStartService = true;
}@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, FatLinkService.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(bIntent);
    getApplicationContext().bindService(bIntent, flConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
} 
// service connection to bind idle service
private ServiceConnection flConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
       linkService.MyLinkBinder flBinder = (LinkService.MylinkBinder) binder;
       flServiceInstance = flBinder.getService();
       if (onlyStartService) {
           condLog("Service bound and finishing activity...");
           finish();
       }
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        flServiceInstance = null;
    }
}; 
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (fatFinish) {
        Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, FatLinkService.class);
        flServiceInstance.stopServices();
        flServiceInstance.stopForeground(true);
        flServiceInstance.stopService(bIntent);
        condLog("Service stop and unbound");
        flServiceInstance = null;
    }
    getApplicationContext().unbindService(flConnection);
}
```

This is how service is:

```
public class LinkService extends Service {
    InetAddress iaIpAddr, iaNetMask, iaBroadcast;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyLinkBinder();
    private linklistenBroadcast flBroadServer = null;
    private linkTCPServer flTCPServer = null;
    private linkUDPClient flBroadClient = null;
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

public class MylLinkBinder extends Binder {
    lLinkService getService() { return LinkService.this; }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    getLocks();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{        
    instantiateServices();
    // notifies presence to other fat devices
    condLog("Service notifying fat presence...");
    flBroadClient = new LinkUDPClient();
    flBroadClient.startSending(LinkProtocolConstants.BRCMD_PRESENCE + String.valueOf(LinkProtocolConstants.tcpPort), iaBroadcast, LinkProtocolConstants.brPort);
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void getLocks() {
    // acquire a WakeLock to keep the CPU running
    condLog("Acquiring power lock");
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL , "MyWifiLock");
    wifiLock.acquire();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

public void stopServices() {
    if (flTCPServer != null)
        flTCPServer.stopServer();
    if (flBroadServer != null)
        flBroadServer.stopSelf();
}

private void instantiateServices() {
    populateAddresses(); // just obtain iaIpAddr  
    if (flTCPServer == null) {
        condLog("Instantiating TCP server");
        flTCPServer = new LinkTCPServer(iaIpAddr, FatLinkProtocolConstants.tcpPort);
        flTCPServer.execute();
    }
    if (flBroadServer == null) {
        condLog("Instantiating UDP broadcast server");
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, LinkMain.class); // this is the main Activity class
        notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        notifyIntent.setAction("FROM_NOTIFICATION");
        PendingIntent notifyPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);

        Notification fixNotification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("Link")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.imgLink)
                .setContentIntent(notifyPIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1234, fixNotification);
        flBroadServer = new LinklistenBroadcast();
        flBroadServer.start();
    }
}

private final class LinklistenBroadcast extends Thread {
    private boolean bStopSelf = false;
    DatagramSocket socket;
    public void stopSelf() {
        bStopSelf = true;
        socket.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        condLog( "Listening broadcast thread started");
        bStopSelf = false;
        try {
        //Keep a socket open to listen to all the UDP trafic that is destinated for this port
        socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.setSoTimeout(LinkGeneric.BR_SOTIMEOUT_MILS);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"), FatLinkProtocolConstants.brPort));
        while (true) {
                condLog("Ready to receive broadcast packets...");
                //Receive a packet
                byte[] recvBuf = new byte[1500];

                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
                try {
                    socket.receive(packet);
                } catch (InterruptedIOException sException) {
                    condLog(sockExcept.toString());
                    break;
                } catch (SocketException sockExcept) {
                   condLog(sockExcept.toString());
                }
                if (bStopSelf) {
                    condLog("Broadcast server stopped...");
                    break;
                }
                int len = packet.getLength();
                String datarecvd = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
                //datarecvd = datarecvd.substring(0, len);
                //Packet received
                String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
                condLog("<<< broadcast packet received from: " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " on port: " + packet.getPort() + ", message: " + message);
                if (packet.getAddress().equals(iaIpAddr)) {
                    condLog("Ooops, it's me! discarding packet...");
                    continue;
                }
                else
                    condLog("<<< Packet received; data size: " + len + " bytes, data: " +  datarecvd);

                //See if the packet holds the right command (message)

                // protocol decode
                // here do some tuff
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            condLog(ex.toString());
        }

        if (socket.isBound()) {
            condLog( "Closing socket");
            socket.close();
        }
        condLog( "UDP server thread end.");
        flTCPServer = null;
        flBroadServer = null;
    }

    public boolean isThreadRunning() {
        return !bStopSelf;
    };
}

// Utility functions
public boolean checkBroadcastConnection (DatagramSocket socket, int timeOutcycles) {
    int tries = 0;
    while (!socket.isConnected()) {
        tries++;
        if (tries >= timeOutcycles)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (wakeLock != null) {
        if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.release();                
        }
    }
    if (wifiLock != null) {
        if (wifiLock.isHeld()) {
            wifiLock.release();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And, finally, here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxxxx.ink" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/imgLinkmascotte"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LinkMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".LinkService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

- I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911700/wifilock-and-wakelock-not-working-correctly-on-android), and I have the doubt the problem is the same but it is actually happening to me on all the phone I have tried (galaxy Tab 7.1, galaxy tag 10, Galaxy SIII, Galaxy Note 3 Neo, Galaxy SIII mini) with android releases from 4.0 to 4.4.
- I have already tried the solution posted [here](http://PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), but anything changed (again...it is a bit frustrating).
- I have even tried to set the "Keep wifi option in standby" to "Always" in all the phones I've tried, but still nothing.
- I have studied the WakeFulIntentService class, that is supposed to work as everybody is saying that it is, but I can't see any significant different in my code.

I really hope someone can help me, I'm really stuck on this since last week.

EDIT: following the waqaslam answer, I have checked on a device that has "Wifi optimisation" option in Wifi-Advaced settings, and it actually works as soon as I uncked the option. So, now, the problem become: can I disable Wifi optimisation in devices that haven't that option shown in the advanced menu? as I wrote below in my comment, this seems not to be related to android release, as I have two devices (both Samsung) with 4.4.2 and they are not showing the option.

New EDIT: from the edited waqaslam answer, I have tried to add multicastlock to my service, but again anything changed. This is getting annoying, there's hardly something easy and clear to do with android.

thank you very much
C.

Comment: What is your android version and device?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wrote them at the end of the post. More precisely, I have tried with 4.0.x (don't rememebr now exactly), 4.1.2 and 4.4.2.

Comment: I am going through the same annoying problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No way. With the broadcast is simply not possible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing that just to mark the post as answered. I finally realilzed that there is no solution, or at least there is no solution working well on "all" the phones with "all" the android distribution (or at least from JB).

I have solved my personal issue just revisiting the concept of my app, considering that:
- Sending UDP broadcast is always working even in idle mode
- TCP servers are not affected by WiFi optimisation.

thank you all for the help and suggestion
C.

Comment: **"Sending `UDP` broadcast is always working even in idle mode..."**, did you mean `TCP`?

Comment: My service is awaiking every 2 secs sending an UDP broadcast packet, and this is working in idle mode with display off too. Can you really send/receive a broadcast with TCP?

Comment: No, you cannot do that with TCP. But as an alternate, I would suggest you to go for a client-server model, where your client (mobile) is registered with server using TCP socket. Or more preferably, look for **XMPP** based solutions which are more sophisticated and reliable (but a little complex implementation) in terms of message handling on the network.

Comment: Thank you waqaslam for your valuable suggestions. Unfortunately, in my case a client/server model is not appliable, or bettert, is appliable and I'm using it but only after the broadcast is used to notify presence to all nodes of the net.

Comment: @CristianoZambon I had the same problem. At beginning I used multicast. I switched to broadcast just to try but I tested at least on some phones broadcast it's not reliable too. Only TCP unicast is reliable on all android devices.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not with the WakeLocks but the Wi-Fi settings.

In newer versions of android, there's an additional setting in **<kbd>Settings</kbd>  -> <kbd>Wi-Fi</kbd> -> <kbd>Advanced</kbd>** called `Wi-Fi optimization`, which (if turned-on) disables all the low priority communications (like listening to UDP broadcasts) when the display is off.

Disabling the option should allow your device to listen UDP broadcasts even when the display is switched-off.

[image: Wi-Fi optimization]

---

You may also use [`WifiManager.MulticastLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html) in order to acquire WiFi lock that should listen to these special broadcasts when screen is switched-off.

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("lockWiFiMulticast");
lock.setReferenceCounted(false);
lock.acquire();
```

and when done with the lock, then call:

```
lock.release();
```

Also, don't forget to add the following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```

For more info, you may read [this](https://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP).

Comment: Thank you for the anwer. In my Note 3 Neo with Android 4.4.2 there isn't this option, I only have "Keep wifi on during sleep", that I put to "Always".

Comment: What about those devices which have this option, can you try on them? I also experienced a similar problem few months back and disabling that option helped me to solve the it.

Comment: yes, just tried on a One plus One with android 4.4.2 and that option present. Unchecking this option it actually works. So, the new question is, how to let devices witout this option work too?

Comment: Technically, devices which do not have this option should work fine by default. But in case they don't then it's the classical case where device manufacturer (with custom roms) has limited this feature in order to compensate performance (like battery life) and/or security. However, you may still acquire this by using `MulticastLock`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your comment and asnwer. This time I was really hoping it was the solution but unfortyunatley not, the service is still not answering when display go off.

Answer (score 0):

May be the reason is [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases) .

> Starting from Android 6.0 (API level 23), Android introduces two
>   power-saving features that extend battery life for users by managing
>   how apps behave when a device is not connected to a power source. Doze
>   reduces battery consumption by deferring background CPU and network
>   activity for apps when the device is unused for long periods of time.
>   App Standby defers background network activity for apps with which the
>   user has not recently interacted