# wakeLock and wifiLock

Tags: java, android

When I start service which send some data to server every few seconds I acquire

wakeLock

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

and wifiLock

```
WifiManager wMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiLock = wMgr.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "MyWifiLock");
    wifiLock.acquire();
```

But if device is not touched for one hour and is in sleep mode wifi stop working. Is this normal behaviour and if not, what should I do to lock device until `release()` method are called?

Comment: Where did you acquire the lock? `Activity` or `Service`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17502967/8460132

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android dozes off the device when it is left unused for some time to optimise battery performance, so yes it is a normal behaviour.

Firstly, it is highly recommended for that you don't try to stop the device going to doze off mode, for the betterment of battery performance of the device. You can read more about dozing off here in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

If you have a strict requirement for some reason that you need to keep your service active, you can probably try adding [REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) permission in your app. But be advised that your app may get rejected from the Google Play Store (if it is supposed to be published there) on the basis of the quotation below from the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases):

> Note: Google Play policies prohibit apps from requesting a direct exemption from Power Management features in Android 6.0+ (Doze and App Standby) unless the core function of the app is adversely affected.